# select null as testdate into #temp_table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, temp-tables

Is there a way to insert/update a datetime value (`getdate()`) into a temp table created like the following:

```
select id, null as testdate
into #temp_table
```

and then later statement:

```
update #temp_table 
set testdate=getdate()
```

I get error:

> cannot convert datetime into int...

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cast the column in the select into

```
select id, cast(null as datetime) as testdate
into #temp_table
```

Comment: +1: Exactly. NULL by default in SQL Server is an INT; you need to CAST/CONVERT the NULL to the appropriate data type for the OP's stuff to work.

Comment: +1: Another example of why I always prefer to explicitly create my temp tables.